# what APIs have been hooked in Cuckoo sandbox

Tags: malware

As I know, Cuckooo sandbox hooks all APIs to intercept and log for the analysis. Could you please tell me what type of APIs have been hooked? Are they system call API or they are high level API?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/cuckoo/latest/cuckoo.pdf shows it uses Volatility. Volatility lists the hooks here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/volatility/wikis/CommandReference.wiki#apihooks

Comment: There is a list from 2015 on their GitHub wiki: https://github.com/cuckoosandbox/cuckoo/wiki/Hooked-APIs-and-Categories